# Addition of BearerToken Authorization Header in DelegatingHandler ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, bearer-token, delegatinghandler

Why if I add **authorization header with right token** in my custom DelegatingHandler to the request without this header, I get the response: 401 authorization required?

```
public class ProxyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
   protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer rightToken...");
        return response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

If I send the request from postman **with the same authorization header**, I got 200 OK.
[image]

Comment: I do not understand the first paragraph. Maybe you can re-phrase it as a question and make your sentences shorter for better understanding.

Comment: Sorry, I will try to make it simpler ;)

Comment: Can you also show the complete code sample that uses your `DelegatingHandler`?

Comment: I have added ProxyHandler.cs in WebApiConfig.cs (config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ProxyHandler());)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The method AuthenticateCoreAsync from OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler.cs class was fired before my ProxyHandler.
After I have changed **AuthenticationMode** in OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions **from Active to Passive**, request token in header is being checked after method base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken) from my ProxyHandler is fired.